# how the dbeaver get the mysql column real type, where is the source code

Tags: sqldatatypes, dbeaver

when I execute `select * from mysql.columns_priv;` in dbeaver, it will return result data.

[image]

I found that Column_priv type is set(xxx).
But when I check the metadata, the Column_priv type is CHAR, and the JDBC type is also CHAR, so how the dbeaver get the real type from mysql?

[image]

I try to read dbeaver source code from github, but I can not found it.

I try to debug dbeaver by modify dbeaver.ini, dbeaver will start failed.

Comment: Does dbeaver need the datatype?  Simply `... col_name = 'literal' ...` works for all datatypes.